# Change the date format to its respective month and year only in python

Tags: python

I have a date say - `25-Jan-19`

I want to convert it to  - `Jan19` in python. What date format I'll have to use to get this?

Comment: Oh, and what's 19 in your example? Is it the 19th day in January or is it part of the year? If part of a year, is it the year 2019 or 1919 or 1819, etc.?

Comment: Its basically Jan 2019...in short Jan19

Comment: and I have a particular column name date

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%b%y')` this works

Answer (score 1):

If `25-Jan-19` is a string and will always be in this format, you can try this:-

```
date = date.split("-")
date = "".join(date[i] for i in range(1,len(date)))
```